# Loop through the data frames in a list, filter data as per if condition and update a column in the data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have
3 Dataframes all alike with headers (count of data frames can be dynamic)-

1. Model - "CARENS", "CARNIVAL", "CLARUS", "EV6", "NIRO"
2. Age - "0 to 2", "3", "4", "5", "6 to 9"
3. ZD - "ZD", "NZD", "Z", "N", "ZND"
4. NCB - "0-25", "35-45", "50-65", "
5. FUEL - "Diesel", "Petrol, "CNG", "Electric"
6. CC - "<=1000", "1000<=1500", ">1500"
7. RTO - "Mumbai", "Ahmedabad", "Pune"
8. Discount - 0.63, 0.83 .....

Data frame names - DATA_KIA, DATA_HONDA, DATA_HYUNDAI

I have a code that alters data in Discount column for 1 data frame based on the values of other columns.

***DATA_KIA$Discount <- ifelse(DATA_KIA$AGE == "0 to 2"& DATA_KIA$ZD == "ZD"& DATA_KIA$MODEL == "CARENS"& DATA_KIA$RTO == "AHMEDABAD",0.83,DATA_KIA$DISCOUNT)***

But, if I have to edit data in other data frames, I will have to change data frame name in my code every time. Count of data frames in future can go up to 20. Instead of doing it 1 at a time, is there a way for me to alter data in all data frames with a single query?

Comment: Use mget with pattern, see this answer from linked post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37635979/680068

Comment: @zx8754, mget only helps in forming the list. If i need to run a if and code (if cc>1000, fuel = petrol, then discount = 50%). Mget query is dfList <- mget(ls(pattern="^DATA_"))

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I have edited and added an example for reference.

Comment: While better, it's still not reproducible. There's no code we can copy/paste into R to test with. There's no sample input or desired output for that input. We don't need 10 data frames in the example; 3 three would probably be enough, and we don't really need all the columns you aren't filtering on.  Why do you insist on them being separate data.frame variables in the global environment? It just makes them harder to work with. Lists of values are just much easier to work with in R.

Comment: @MrFlick, for sample purpose yes even 3 would do. I might use other columns for filtering in future. I receive all data in data frames so can't help it. I have edited the question and written a sample code for 1 data frame that i might want to implement for 1,2 or 3 data frames depending on the conditions that it satisfies.